# AWS Lambda - Nested Lambdas Error Handling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am struggling with Lambda error handling . When I use call one lambda via Api Gateway , there is no problem. For example when a RuntimeException occurs, Api Gateway takes it and serializes to json string , so i am able to handle with this. 
But I have no opininon how to deal with nested Lambdas error handling. For example we have three lambda L1,L2,L3.
L1 calls-> L2 calls -> L3 
If there is an error in L3 . How can I handle it ?
I appriciate if any suggestion or external link.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Part of it depends on how you are invoking your lambdas through each other...I assume you are using the SDK to invoke L2 from L1 and L3 from L2 and so on. Assuming this, you should be able to call your callback in L3 (with err) when there is an error and then expect to handle that in L2 in the callback of the function invoking L3. If L2's call to L3 returns with error != null, then you call the callback with err and configure L1 to handle. You basically pass your error up the chain by designing the invoking lambda to handle errors from the invoked lambda. Let me know if this helps...if desired, I can include some pseudocode or NodeJS sample code in a bit when I am at a dedicated computer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Java Psuedo code will be super if it is possible.